# Bluetooth Printing in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, printing, bluetooth, native

Is it possible to connect to thermal receipt printer via Bluetooth in react native? If yes the how to connect receipt printer via Bluetooth in react native?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to connect a React Native app to Printer via Bluetooth.
The package called [react-native-ble-plx](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) allows you to do so. Read their documentation at [Github.io](https://polidea.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `react-native-ble-manager`: [Full source code can be found here](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Star printers, I would go with this library:
https://github.com/infoxicator/react-native-star-prnt